# How to mount host folder into Docker container keeping host read-only, but writeable in container

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab

Is it possible to have a folder on the host volume mounted into a container, keeping the host folder read-only while allowing the container to modify the files in its own overlay?

Use case: we have a GitLab instance using the Docker executor managed by chef. GitLab runner spins up a container which does deployments for us. We have a shared SSH key on the host that we mount into the container which allows us to ssh into all our servers and deploy.

Problem: We have other teams that also use our GitLab instance. They need to ssh into their servers. They overwrite the id_rsa allowing them to connect, but this writes into the host folder, which then in turn breaks our pipelines.

Is it possible to have Docker pull the certificates in and only allow one-way writing to the container layer?

Comment: I don't think that's possible, but it also seems to be a roundabout way of solving the problem.  Can you move ssh key to someplace in the container filesystem that isn't on the host volume?

Comment: We could, but we use chef to manage the gitlab instance as well as all the servers, so the key is maintained in one central place (chef-vault) and then cheffed onto the servers and the gitlab runner. Having to manually go and put it into every pipeline would sort of defeat the purpose of using chef at all